# w3c markup validation: Attribute duration not allowed on element li at this point

Tags: html-lists, w3c-validation, duration

I'm getting this error when I validate through w3c validator:

> Attribute duration not allowed on element li at this point.

```
<li data-text-id="#bannerscollection_kenburns_photoText3" data-horizontalPosition="center" data-verticalPosition="center" data-initialZoom="1" data-finalZoom="1" duration="5" >
```

Somebody please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<li data-text-id="#bannerscollection_kenburns_photoText3" data-horizontalPosition="center" data-verticalPosition="center" data-initialZoom="1" data-finalZoom="1" data-duration="5" >
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, the attribute `duration` is not allowed for the element `li`, as you can easily check in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element):

> **Content attributes:**
>
> - Global attributes
> - If the element is a child of an `ol` element: `value`

`duration` is *not* a [global attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes).

You could prefix it with `data-`, as you do it with all the other attributes, too. But then, *if* you use a third-party tool that needs a `duration` attribute, it would not work anymore. (You didn't say anything about a tool in your question, though.)